# Bind events to all elements in class instead of just to one id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I developed this interaction / script that scales whatever element is passed to it and if that element is pinched in on, it scales down / less.

This is how the script is initialised ( passing two arguments the container and the item to be scaled / transformed:

```
$(function(){
var zoom = new collapse('#zoom','#zoom :first');
var zoom2 = new collapse('#zoom2','#zoom2 :first');
var zoom3 = new collapse('#zoom3','#zoom3 :first');
});
```

It works fine as above on single IDs, but I need it to work on a class.

I tried this:

```
$(function(){
var zoom = new collapse('#zoom','.polaroid');
});
```

But that causes the whole script not to work because all the elements in that class are being passed instead of one as with an id.

This would only select the first item in the class so it won't work:

```
$(function(){
var zoom = new collapse('#zoom','.polaroid :first');
});
```

How can I change my script so that it is applied to all members of the .polaroid class in the #main container?

Here is my script:

```
function collapse(container, element){
container = $(container).hammer({
    prevent_default: true,
    scale_threshold: 0
});
element = $(element);
var displayWidth = container.width();
var displayHeight = container.height();
var MIN_ZOOM = 0;
var MAX_ZOOM = 1;
var scaleFactor = 1;
var previousScaleFactor = 1;
var startX = 0;
var startY = 0;
var translateX = 0;
var translateY = 0;
var previousTranslateX = 0;
var previousTranslateY = 0;
var time = 1;
var tch1 = 0,
    tch2 = 0,
    tcX = 0,
    tcY = 0,
    toX = 0,
    toY = 0,
    cssOrigin = "";
container.bind("transformstart", function(event){
    e = event;
    tch1 = [e.touches[0].x, e.touches[0].y],
        tch2 = [e.touches[1].x, e.touches[1].y];
    tcX = (tch1[0]+tch2[0])/2,
        tcY = (tch1[1]+tch2[1])/2;
    toX = tcX;
    toY = tcY;
    var left = $(element).offset().left;
    var top = $(element).offset().top;
    cssOrigin = (-(left) + toX)/scaleFactor +"px "+ (-(top) + toY)/scaleFactor +"px";
});
container.bind("transform", function(event){
    scaleFactor = previousScaleFactor * event.scale;
    scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM));
    transform(event);
});
container.bind("transformend", function(event){
    previousScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
    if(scaleFactor > 0.42){
        $(element).css('-webkit-transform', 'scaleY(1.0)').css('transform', 'scaleY(1.0)');
    }
});
function transform(e){
    var cssScale = "scaleY("+ scaleFactor +")";
    element.css({
        webkitTransform: cssScale,
        webkitTransformOrigin: cssOrigin,
        transform: cssScale,
        transformOrigin: cssOrigin,
    });
    if(scaleFactor <= 0.42){
        $(element).animate({height:0}, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it as a jquery plugin:

```
$.fn.collapse = function(filter) {
    return this.each(function(){
        collapse(this,filter);
    });
}

$("#zoom,#zoom1,#zoom2").collapse(".polaroid");
```

or if each of the zoom elements had a common class,

```
$(".zoomel").collapse(".polaroid");
```

Comment: Ah, I see...Thank you! Do you know how I can make it so the event delegates too? I tried using jQuery's .on() instead of .bind, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I dont understand what you want to delegate, and i don't think delegation would be relevant in this case. Plugins generally have to be called on new elements when they are created, they don't have a way of automatically being initialized on new elements.

Comment: So some of the items of the class are programmatically written to the DOM on scroll, like infinite scrolling, and these ones do not have the event bounded to them. The interaction does work on these ones only the ones originally in the DOM. This is an event delegation problem, isn't it?

Comment: That is the issue, but since this is a plugin/function not an event, delegation doesn't make sense. Use the success/complete callback of the code adding new elements. Delegation only works with events.

Comment: You mean initialise this plugin again in the callback of the javascript that creates the new elements?

Comment: Yes, but make sure you only target the new elements.

Comment: How do I do that? Why shouldn't I target the whole class again?

Comment: you shouldn't target the whole class again because you'll end up with multiple events bound to the previous elements that had the class.

Comment: I got that, but why is that bad?

Comment: because... you will get duplicated events. that's why it's bad. you'll click once, and the action will happen 30 times.

Comment: Oh, yeah that does sound bad. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: One more question. I finally tried turning it into a plugin. It works, but now all the members of the class are transformed / scaled. How can I get it to transform / scale only the item the pinch in is happening on?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run collapse for each element.

```
element = $(element);
element.each(function(){
   //each element would be this here
   var $this=  $(this);
   //do whatever you want with $this
})
```